# Showing first 5 elements from the list

Tags: jquery, list, append, each

I want to dynamically show first 5 elements from an appended list. I tried this but it isn't working:

```
$(this).find("element").each(['1','2','3'], function (){...
$("#rounded_items").append('<li id="'+ level +'"><div class="item_pocket"><img src="'+ image +'" class="image"/><span>'+ name +'</span></div></li>')
```

Comment: your array length is 3 still you want  length of 5?

Comment: this is an axample, it may be 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: @diEcho - That does'nt really matter, as `element.each()`. does'nt work that way, but `$.each` could have, so probably read the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    $(this).find("element:lt(5)").each(function(){...}
```